# Prophet / fbprophet package in Python

Tags: python, installation, facebook-prophet

Can someone explain how to install Prophet on Python3?

I tried `pip install fbprophet` but it did not work.

Tried to do this in the notebook after importing pandas and sklearn and got another error:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
from fbprophet import Prophet
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f503e9c6cf11> in <module>()
----> 1 from fbprophet import Prophet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet'
```

Comment: If you really typed `pip install fbprohet`, that has a typo (missing p) so it won't work. What does `pip list` (List installed packages) show?

Comment: the typo is here not in install. My fault.

Comment: the list is way too long

Comment: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
Failed to build fbprophet
Installing collected packages: pystan, fbprophet
  Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error
  
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\fbprophet
    creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model

    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.

Comment: If the typo is here, then fix it. Typos in questions are no use to anyone.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 ?

Comment: Did you install pystan first, as mentioned in the fbprophet instructions?
 https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Typo has been already corrected. Pystan was installed. Not sure about Visual C++

Comment: you need to install pystan first

Answer (score 9):

First you have to Install c++ compiler, you can install c++ compiler with below command -

```
conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
```

Once c++ compiler installed you have to install pystan, to install pystan you can use below command

```
pip install pystan
```

Finally, now we are ready to install facebook prophet -

```
pip install fbprophet
```

Hope this is helpful..

For more details follow this link -
https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way is to install `fbprophet` :

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

This will download all the needed packages first.

Then ->

```
  conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 fbprophet
```

Comment: This is correct and its works for me. Thank you so much @Nishad.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing `fbprophet`

`pip install fbprophet`

Or

`pip3 install fbprophet`

Answer (score 3):

I had relatively similar problem, but my error was it couldn't import `pystan` which in installed using `pip install pystan`. so the problem was `fbprophet` doesn't support latest version of `pystan` so uninstall previous one and install older version of pystan.

`pip install pystan==2.19.1.1`
`pip install fbprophet`

https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html

Answer (score 2):

On Windows it's easier using anaconda or miniconda, just give

```
conda install pystan
```

and it will install all the needed dependencies, included the c++ compiler, then

```
pip install fbprophet
```

in Linux systems, for example, ubuntu, a simple

```
pip install pystan
pip install fbprophet
```

should work, without installing anaconda/miniconda

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I have been trying to solve it for two days now
I found out that `fbprophet` is no longer being maintained and that's why `pip install fbprophet` does not work.

do `pip install prophet` instead

if you want to import after installation: `from prophet import Prophet`

Answer (score 0):

!pip install pystan==2.19.1.1 fbprophet ##### i was trying to install fbprophet==0.7.1 but in the presence of cmdstanpy==0.9.5 it was unable to build the wheel for fbprophet.
after executing the above command for installing pystan==2.19.1.1 collectively with fbprophet successfully installed cmdstanpy-0.9.5 fbprophet-0.7.1 note that there is no version specified for fbprophet in the command and pystan is specified with version 2.19.1.1 to avoid dependency conflicts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. **pip3** was a must!

```
pip3 install pystan 
pip3 install fbprophet
```

Answer (score 0):

according to it's [document](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#installation-in-python), new version was renamed to `prophet` and can be installed with:

```
python -m pip install prophet
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

Answer (score 0):

Pip install can be done since Prophet is on PyPI;

`python -m pip install prophet`

It can also be installed through conda-forge;

`conda install -c conda-forge prophet`