# fbprophet installation in conda env failed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, facebook-prophet

I want to install the package `fbprophet` (it may now also be known as `prophet`). I tried importing both like so (not all at once):

```
import fbprophet
import prophet
from fbprophet import Prophet
from prophet import Prophet
```

Error I receive is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5908/2493871459.py in <module>
----> 1 from prophet import Prophet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'
```

I have already gone through all the other questions asking the same problem, yet those solutions didn't work for me. I also tried changing python version to 3.7 when installing it in a new env for testing purposes.

[installing prophet in jupyter nb](https://medium.com/data-folks-indonesia/installing-fbprophet-prophet-for-time-series-forecasting-in-jupyter-notebook-7de6db09f93e)

[No module named 'fbprophet'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353951/no-module-named-fbprophet)

[Prophet / fbprophet package in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808322/prophet-fbprophet-package-in-python)

[some code solution for installation](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1242)

Comment: If I try to install the `fbprophet` package from anaconda navigator, it is not at all visible (anaconda navigator version is 2.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create a fresh conda environment for `prophet`. You will avoid conflicts and let conda retrieve without any other constraints the required dependencies. Here is how to do it as per the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#python).

```sh
# create a new env called prophet
# with no other spec than prop
conda create -c conda-forge -n prophet prophet
```

Use the env.

```sh
# activate the env
conda activate prophet
# test
python -c "import prophet; print(prophet.__version__)"
# Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
# 1.0
```

Register it as a Jupyter Kernel as per the [doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

```sh
# install ipykernl
conda install ipykernel
# register it
python -m ipykernel install --user --name prophet --display-name "Prophet"
```

[image: Notebook running prophet]

Comment: i followed the above code, and tried importing prophet in the jupyter notebook cell using the Prophet kernel, the kernel then became dead whilst executing. However, in the anaconda terminal, when i run python and execute `import prophet` it works

Comment: @varunavi sorry to hear that. On my side it's running like a charm from a fresh install, I've uploaded a screenshot.