# Cannot install fbprophet

Tags: python, pip, conda, cpython, facebook-prophet

c:\users\gmmke\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)

when I install 'fbphrophet' using pip I get the following error;

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [6 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\gmmke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xqjndm3g\pystan_f741f659e9174f8b8c290e2185389721\setup.py", line 122, in <module>
      from Cython.Build.Inline import _get_build_extension
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have the latest pip version

```
C:\Users\gmmke\Desktop\Stocks Predictions>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied:pip in c:\users\gmmke\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)
```

Cython is aready installed

I followed this article
[Prophet / fbprophet package in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808322/prophet-fbprophet-package-in-python).
And did;

```
conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
```

and also;

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

But still did not work.
Same error as above for `pip install pystan`

Comment: Even on Google Notebooks its the same
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
Failed to build fbprophet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fbprophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projct

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546) (or [\[SO\]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure to double check where Conda is installed. Check that you are in the correct conda as well as pip environment for installing the package

Comment: its done correctly 

C:\Users\gmmke\Desktop\Stocks Predictions>Conda --version
conda 23.7.3